# Displaying New tab after clicking a tag

Tags: hyperlink, hugo, hugo-shortcode

I am new to Hugo and I want to quickly make a portfolio to display my Google Drive Excel sheet, so I downloaded a theme. Here's a template that generates Markdown that I have been trying to edit:

```
<p>{{. | markdownify}}</p>
```

I want clicks on links generated by `markdownify` (in that `p` tag) to open in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can [adjust the global Markdown rendering settings](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration-markup#blackfriday) to make links in Markdown always open in a new tab by using the Blackfriday Markdown renderer and setting the `hrefTargetBlank` flag. Add this to your `config.toml` (or the equivalent in YAML/JSON)

```toml
[markup]
defaultMarkdownHandler = 'blackFriday'
[blackFriday]
hrefTargetBlank = true
```

If you need more complicated logic to determine when to make links open in a new tab or need to use the Goldmark Markdown renderer, you can use the [`render-link` render hook](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration-markup/#markdown-render-hooks) to override the output of the Markdown renderer with a template. The simplest render hook to do this would be this (in `layouts/_default/_markup/render-link.html`). See the documentation for the full details on this.

```html
<a href="{{ .Destination | safeURL }}" {{ with .Title}}title="{{ . }}"{{ end }} target="_blank">{{ .Text | safeHTML }}</a>
```